# Executar Adobe Flash no Google Chrome

Tags: google, google-chrome, flash

Estou recebendo a mensagem "Reiniciar o Chrome para ativar o plug-in Adobe Flash Player", mas já reiniciei, reinstalei, desliguei e liguei o SO, verifiquei atualizações do plug-in e do navegador e nada resolveu.

Alguma sugestão de como proceder?

---

- OS: Xubuntu 17.10 64bits
- Versão do Chrome: 64.0.3282.140 (Versão oficial) 64 bits
- Adobe Flash: 28.0.0.161 (Status - Atualizado)

Comment: Cara verifica se o plugin está ativado. Vai em no menu do Chrome no canto superior direito, depois Mais Ferramentas > Extensões e verifica se está ativado. Se não rolar desinstala, vai no site da Adobe e instala o plugin por lá https://get.adobe.com/br/flashplayer/

Answer (score 0):

Você fez o procedimento especificado pelo google para ativar?

Só permita que conteúdos em Flash sejam executados em sites em que você confia.

```
No computador, abra o Chrome.
Acesse o site do vídeo ou jogo. 
À esquerda do endereço da Web, clique em Bloquear Bloquear ou Informações Informações.
À direita de "Flash", clique nas setas Setas.
Selecione Sempre permitir neste site.
No canto superior esquerdo, clique em Atualizar Atualizar.
```

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=pt-BR

Se mesmo assim não estiver funcionando, tenta reiniciar o chrome na aba de atualização (Vai atualizar para a versão  64.0.3282.167):

```
No computador, abra o Google Chrome.
No canto superior direito, clique em Mais Mais.
Clique em Ajuda e depois em Sobre o Google Chrome
Clique em atualizar
Clique em Reiniciar.
```